# Wireless network using existing network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I am trying to accomplish the following, I know its possible as I have set this same scenario up previously, but with a Aruba solution, which made it easier.

I have an exsisting LAN (192.168.0.1-254) and want to setup wireless on this network, but keeping the wireless on 192.168.1.1 and have it pass directly thru to the internet, with no access to the LAN 192.168.0.1.

With Netgear wireless access points, how can I accomplish this, is it as simple as setting up a router with a IP of 192.168.1.1, setting static IP addresses on the wireless access points, and having the router on 192.168.1.1 assign DHCP on the wireless, or will it hand out IP addresses to the LAN connections as well?

Answer (score 0):

It's that simple.  A separate router for the APs will make the two networks completely segregated.

More advanced SMB and enterprise routers can do this from one device, but consumer grade equipment usually doesn't support the VLANs necessary to pull that off.

Comment: So using the same wiring for the AP as the LAN network, but statically assigning the IP to the AP will be ok. How do I prevent the additional router from handing out IP addresses to the LAN connections ?

Comment: Hmmm... can you clarify what you mean by "using the same wiring"?  If the router, AP, and any switches are all dedicated to the WLAN, you should be okay.  If at any point the two networks share a switch or router, there's potential for problems.

Comment: The house wiring, that makes up the LAN network, it is used by both the physical connections for 192.168.0.1 and for the wireless access points for the 192.168.1.1, in essence they are on the same network.
If they use the same wiring, without being able to break out and tag for VLAN, how can I prevent the router, associated with the gateway of the wireless, from handing out IP addresses to devices on the LAN 192.168.0.1 ?

Comment: Yeah, without physical segregation or VLANs, it won't work.